# What's the difference between "Clang with Microsoft CodeGen" and "LLVM-vs2014"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, clang, llvm

Under Visual Studio 2015 or later, we can use clang in two ways:

> 1. Select `Clang with Microsoft CodeGen` as the `Platform Toolset`;
> 2. Install `LLVM-3.8-win64.exe`, and select `LLVM-vs2014` as the `Platform Toolset`;

I know both of the two ways use the same compiler: `clang 3.8`. However, I don't know what the difference is between them.

My experience shows `Clang with Microsoft CodeGen` is more debugging-friendily than `LLVM-vs2014`. In other words:

> 1. I can debug a program built by `Clang with Microsoft CodeGen` step by step as VC++ does;
> 2. A program built by "LLVM-vs2014" cannot be debugged step by step at source-level, but the program can direct run as expected.

So, my questions are:

Does `LLVM-vs2014` not support source-level debugging under Visual Studio?

Is `Clang with Microsoft CodeGen` provided by Microsoft only for supporting source-level debugging under Visual Studio?

Comment: Clang only provides the front-end of the compiler.  Better error reporting is its claim to fame.  Somebody else provides the back-end, code generator and optimizer.  That is Microsoft's if you use the VS provided toolset.  But you bring your own with LLVM if you use the other.  They don't do a lot of banging on the drum about it, exception handing was traditionally the sticking point.  And sure, debugging is an issue, you can't rely on the debugger engines provided by VS.  Looks to me you'll need lldb, also part of the LLVM package.  Clang-cl looks like a front-end tweak to accept MSFT quirks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I know both of the two ways use the same compiler: clang 3.8. However, I don't know what the difference is between them.

The difference is **how** they use it.

`Clang with Microsoft CodeGen` is using Clang to **parse** the source into an AST. But then MSVC's code generator kicks in, so anything related to LLVM is not used.

`LLVM-vs2014` is fully using Clang, for every compiling stage. It uses LLVM to generate the code. So, no wonder debugging info is not compatible with what Visual Studio expects.

it is important to note, that they both use the same runtime. Clang has `clang-cl` mode that enables it to parse Microsoft headers and use their language extensions.

So, the main difference is middle- and back-end stages.